# Counter doesn't increment while using hasMoreTokens

Tags: java

I'm having a problem in my code wherein if I used the `hasMoreTokens` in the for loop (which I copied from a source code for a tokenizer) the value of `b` only adds by 1 (I need it to be incremented by 2 for each pass so i ended up removing the last `for` loop which resulted to my expected result). Why does it only increment by 1 not by 2?

Below is part of my code:

```
for (int a = 1; a <= limit; a++) {
  //while ((input = br.readLine()) != null) {
    input = br.readLine();
    StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(input);
    for (int b = a; b <= limit + count; b++) {
         System.out.println(" " + b);
       //for (int j = 0; st1.hasMoreTokens(); j++) {
         first[b][row] = Integer.parseInt(st1.nextToken());
         System.out.println(first[b][row] + " b: " + b);
         b++;
       //}
     }
   //}
}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's because you wrote it as

```
b++;
```

If you want to increment it by 2 each time it should be

```
b+=2;
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you can do that. But regardless of that, the one i was mentioning was the last for loop which i just placed a comment cause it was the one causing the code not to increment by 2. that's what the post is about.

Comment: @duroy Could you give me a bit more from your code? I don't know what count, first, and limit are initialized to. It probably isn't causing the problem, but I want to make sure that I don't have different values as you when I run it so I can replicate the problem.

Comment: Count is initialized to 0 at the beginning. The code that i provided is the first time that the count is used. The code above is the algorithm i made for the program to output given number into a  diamond shaped text.

example input: 
1
2 3
4
output:
  1
2  3
  4